# RESTEasy+JUnit : Is it possible to test the web services in the same WAR?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, deployment, junit

Is it possible in a JUnit test method to :

1. Deploy REST web services
2. Run a client call from the Junit

in the same war project?

My applicantion architecture is like this :

```
/main/java/here/the/package/to/the/services
/test/java/here/the/package/to/the/junit/methods/using/client
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it with the help of Arquillian. Refer [this](http://arquillian.org/guides/) for more information. Also, do read [this](http://www.hascode.com/2012/04/arquillian-tutorial-writing-java-ee-6-integration-tests-and-more/) for getting started. Hope this would help you !